# How to paste some string in URL Using R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I want to paste some string in dataframe after particular word.

DF_1<-abc
head(abc)
id

I want to paste id after `=` sign in below mentioned link

```
DF_2 <- fromJSON("http://1.1.2.20/b1/erd/nts/avy_tr_Er?size=1000&sortOrder=desc&fdr=as-df-cv-tr")
```

I am using:

```
DF_2 <- fromJSON("http://1.1.2.20/b1/erd/nts/avy_tr_Er?size=1000&sortOrder=desc&fdr=",paste(abc$id),")")
```

But it couldn't work.

Comment: You need to place `paste` outside i.e. `fromJSON(paste("http.... abc$id, sep=""))`

Comment: @akrun can you give me some example.

Comment: Try this example `abc <- data.frame(id = 1000);
str1 <- "http://1.1.2.20/b1/erd/nts/avy_tr_Er?size=1000&sortOrder=desc&fdr=";
paste0(str1, abc$id)#[1] "http://1.1.2.20/b1/erd/nts/avy_tr_Er?size=1000&sortOrder=desc&fdr=1000"`
`

Comment: @akrun Thanks...it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use the `paste` outside i.e.

```
paste0(str1, abc$id)
```

---

Or with `sprintf`

```
sprintf("http://1.1.2.20/b1/erd/nts/avy_tr_Er?size=1000&sortOrder=desc&fdr=%d", abc$id)
```

#### data

```
abc <- data.frame(id = 1000)
str1 <- "http://1.1.2.20/b1/erd/nts/avy_tr_Er?size=1000&sortOrder=desc&fdr="
```